# Can't stop recursion with if() and return

Tags: c++

The problem is "Output all the binary numbers with n amounts of numbers"and I'm asked to solve it using recursion,I managed to completed the task requirement when debugging the code but I still can't stop the recursion even though I set the condition for the loop to stop when all the amount of numbers have the value of 1

```
int anchor_check(vector <int> v)
{
    for(auto iter=v.begin();iter!=v.end();iter++)
        if(*iter==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int testing(int i,int &n,vector <int> v){
    if(anchor_check(v))
        return 0;

    while (i>=0){
        if(v[i]==0){
            v[i]=1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                v[j]=0;
            vector_output(v);//Print out the vector
            testing(n-1,n,v);
        }
        else testing(--i,n,v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int i=n-1;
    vector <int> v(n,0);
    testing(i,n,v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I'm still getting used to using the code format

Comment: what is vector_output? can you please provide the full code including main function?

Comment: Sorry about that,I've edited the code

Answer (score 1):

The function `testing` calls itself. That is called *recursion*. The return statement does not make the function `testing` go away entirely, just the innermost call.

Plus, because `testing` calls itself from within a loop, it will call itself a lot of times.

So once your `anchor_check` finds a result, the current innermost call of testing will return without further recursion. Not so the millions and billions of other calls that are probably made (until you run out of stack or heap space, whatever happens first, and crash).